# Can you pass a SQL query string to Web API controller?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, api

Im trying to build form that constructs a SQL query string depending on the users search preferences and then passes the query to an API controller that gets the data from a database.

```
[Route("api/SelectionHelper/RiskGridView/{query}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage RiskGridView(string query)
    {


        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Actor"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();


                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE key ='" + Constants.GlobalId + "'", con))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    adp.Fill(dt);


                    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No active session found");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        List<RiskSearch> list = new List<RiskSearch>();

                        cmd.CommandText = query;

                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            list.Add(new RiskSearch()
                            {
                                QuoteRef = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ref"]),
                                PolicyRef = reader["reference"].ToString(),
                                Insured = reader["sap_ins_name"].ToString(),
                                QuoteStatus = reader["status"].ToString(),
                                Order = Convert.ToInt32(reader["recd"]),
                                InceptionDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["inception"]).ToShortDateString(),
                                PolicyType = reader["type"].ToString(),
                                Broker = reader["name"].ToString(),
                                QuoteStatusDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"]).ToShortDateString(),
                                RiskStatus = reader["status"].ToString()
                            });
                        }

                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, list);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

How the Query Gets built

```
         if (txt_ref.Text != "")
        {
            SearchString += "[table].[field]" + 
CreatedFunctions.fct_SQL_WhereSearchStringText(txt_ref.Text);
        }
        if (txt_reference.Text != "")
        {
            SearchString += "[Table].[Field]" + 
CreatedFunctions.fct_SQL_WhereSearchStringText(txt_reference.Text);
        }
        if (txtPolicyGroup.Text != "")
        {
            SearchString += "[Table].[Field]" + 
 CreatedFunctions.fct_SQL_WhereSearchStringText(txt_Group_ref.Text);
        }
        if (txt__name.Text != "")
```

I've tried passing the query as a string variable in the url but it throws a 404 or 400 error.

is this the correct way of doing it?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, you *can* pass SQL but that would be incredibly dangerous so, please don't do it.

Comment: Seconded, please never do this.

Comment: I would also say never do that. OTOH not sure I understood. It seems like you already know what the query returns and thus the query itself. Probably saying query you mean something else.

Comment: Your comment was cut off so I don't know how it is built. If you know the return values then you know the query itself, no? Only parameters change.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I know what feilds are going to be returned but the query gets built depending on the user input. For example the user can enter text in the "QuoteReference" textbox and some sql will be added to the query, threes about 30 Fields in the search form an each will add to the query if the user enters data in them. Thus the "WHERE" clause in the query will change each time

Comment: You mean you have a query what is called ad-hoc. Still your query is fixed, parameters are changing. It is C#, and also if it is SQL server, then you could utilize LinqToSQL to build the query for you based on passed parameters (with LinqToEF too but takes more work). Even in case of pure SQL, you could write it with NULL check (accept empty parameters null). BTW I now see a "builder" there and I think its location is wrong (not only that, smells too much SQL injection to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only systems that should be passing SQL *between layers* are things that are *inherently SQL tools* (things like [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), for example).

In all other cases, you should almost certainly be passing some DTO between the layers that represents the available search options, for example

```
public HttpResponseMessage RiskGridView(string reference = null, string policyGroup = null, ... )
```

or via json with:

```
class SearchRequest {
    public string Reference {get;set;}
    public string PolicyGroup {get;set;}
    // ...
}

public HttpResponseMessage RiskGridView(SearchRequest query)
```

Now the `RiskGridView` method would build the required SQL, using **parameters** (not concatenation). The calling system **should not need to know the table layout**.

I would also strongly suggest tools like "Dapper" for actually executing it once constructed:

```
...
if(opt.Reference != null) sql.Append(" and x.Reference=@Reference");
if(opt.PolicyGroup != null) sql.Append(" and x.PolicyGroup=@PolicyGroup");
//...
var results = connection.Query<RiskSearch>(sql.ToString(), opt); // handles params/reader
```

or use a tool like LINQ:

```
IQueryable<RiskSearch> rows = ctx.RiskSearch;
if(opt.Reference != null) rows = rows.Where(x => x.Reference == opt.Reference);
if(opt.PolicyGroup != null) rows.Where(x => x.PolicyGroup == opt.PolicyGroup);
// ...
var results = rows.Take(count).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the required information as query string variables.  **Then, sanity check them.**  Then use a stored procedure and pass them as parameter objects.

Even better would be to use an ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: Note: in most scenarios, there's no particular need or reason to use stored procedures vs correctly parameterized SQL, especially since this is SQL Server (which has efficient handling of ad-hoc parameterized queries).